# How to set strong parameter for many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a model `Word` that has many to many relation `Translation` through junction table `word_to_words`.
The `Translation` is `Word` class itself.

These are source code for it.

#### app/models/word.rb

```
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :word_to_words
  has_many :translations, through: :word_to_words
end
```

#### app/models/word_to_word.rb

```
class WordToWord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :word
  belongs_to :translation, class_name: 'Word'
end
```

#### app/views/words/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(word) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :translations, word.translations.build do |q| -%>
    <%= q.text_field :name %>
  <% end -%>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### app/controllers/words_controller.rb

```
def word_params
  params.require(:word).permit(:name, :pronunciation,
                               word_to_words_attributes: [:word_id, :translation_id],
                               translations_attributes: [:id, :name]
  )
end
```

When I create a new word, the `translation` variable are rejected with error `Unpermitted parameter`.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "word"=>{"name"=>"foo", "translations"=>{"name"=>"bar"}}, "commit"=>"Create Word"}
Unpermitted parameter: translations
```

I think this is because my strong parameter configuration is wrong.
How should I set the strong parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use nested_attributes.

```
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :word_to_words
  has_many :translations, through: :word_to_words
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations
end
```

And the migration canbe:

```
class CreateWordToWords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :word_to_words do |t|
      t.belongs_to :word, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :translation, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```